# Conexant MEDIA install error although it is already installed

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

How to get rid of this annoying problem (showed in the image) as this driver already installed?

[image]

My device is "HP Zbook 15 G3"

I installed Windows 11 instead of Windows 10 that officially is the OS of this model.

I tried everything, but without success.

Comment: Try finding the Windows 11 Driver on the HP Website.  Contact HP Support if that does not work.